# Кривая XML сериализация

Tags: c#, xml, сериализация

Создаю XML файл:

```
<world>
    <country name="Russia">
        <territory>0</territory>
        <residents>0</residents>
    </country>
    <country name="USA">
        <territory>0</territory>
        <residents>0</residents>
    </country>
</world>
```

Написал следующий код:

```
using System;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("country.xml");

XmlElement? xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;

XmlElement Country1 = xDoc.CreateElement("country");
XmlAttribute country1Name = xDoc.CreateAttribute("name");
XmlElement country1territory = xDoc.CreateElement("territory");
XmlElement country1residents = xDoc.CreateElement("residents");

XmlText countryName = xDoc.CreateTextNode("Armenia");
XmlText territoryValue = xDoc.CreateTextNode("29743");
XmlText residentsValue = xDoc.CreateTextNode("2968000");

country1Name.AppendChild(countryName);
country1territory.AppendChild(territoryValue);
country1residents.AppendChild(residentsValue);
Country1.Attributes.Append(country1Name);
Country1.AppendChild(country1territory);
Country1.AppendChild(country1residents);
xRoot?.AppendChild(Country1);

xDoc.Save("country.xml");

country Switzerland = new country(41285, 8698);

XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(country));

//using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("country.xml", FileMode.Open))
//{
//    xmlSerializer.Serialize(fs, Switzerland);

//    Console.WriteLine("Object has been serialized");
//}

//using (FileStream fs1 = new FileStream("country.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
//{
//    country? country3 = xmlSerializer.Deserialize(fs1) as country;
//    Console.WriteLine($"Name: {country3?.name}  Res: {country3?.residents} Ter: {country3?.territory}");
//}

if (xRoot != null)
{
    foreach(XmlElement xnode in xRoot)
    {
        XmlNode? attr = xnode.Attributes.GetNamedItem("name");
        Console.WriteLine(attr?.Value);
        foreach(XmlNode childnode in xnode.ChildNodes)
        {
            if(childnode.Name == "territory")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{childnode.Name}: {childnode.InnerText}");
            }
            if(childnode.Name == "residents")
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"{childnode.Name}: {childnode.InnerText}");
            }
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}



public class country
{
    public int residents { get; set; } = 0;
    public int territory { get; set; } = 0;
    public country()
    {

    }
    public country(int ter,int res)
    {
        territory = ter;
        residents = res;
    }
}
```

Прошу обратить внимание на закоментированную область кода. Все работает хорошо, пока не снять комментарий. Вот так меняется XML файл(до снятия комментариев):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<world>
  <country name="Russia">
    <territory>0</territory>
    <residents>0</residents>
  </country>
  <country name="USA">
    <territory>0</territory>
    <residents>0</residents>
  </country>
  <country name="Armenia">
    <territory>29743</territory>
    <residents>2968000</residents>
  </country>
</world>
```

Все отлично. Теперь давайте сниму комментарий для сериализации:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<country xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <residents>8698</residents>
  <territory>41285</territory>
</country>sidents>
  </country>
  <country name="Armenia">
    <territory>29743</territory>
    <residents>2968000</residents>
  </country>
  <country name="Armenia">
    <territory>29743</territory>
    <residents>2968000</residents>
  </country>
</world>
```

Получается не пойми что. Корневой элемент пропал, атрибут первого элемента "Russia" тоже заменился каким то текстом, при закрытии элемента откуда то берется вот это:

> sidents>

А еще второй раз дублируется страна Армения, хотя я не снял комментарий с десериализации. Подскажите пожалуйста, где ошибка в коде?

Comment: Зачем нужно два `FileStream`? Возможно эта ебурда из-за двойной записи происходит.

Comment: Первый для сериализации, второй для дессериализации

Comment: Сохранили `xDoc` в файл. Затем в этот же файл пишет сериализатор. Новые данные накладываются поверх старых. Отсюда получается `</country>sidents>`

Comment: Если что-то непонятно в комментариях/ответах, не молчите. Редактируйте вопрос, добавляя новую информацию: что сделали, что не получилось, какие ошибки возникают.

Comment: Хорошо, что удалили новый вопрос. Ибо задан он был намного хуже, чем этот.

Comment: Да я уже столько методов перепробовал, и сколько бы не пытался, не понимаю, как сделать, но при разных методах же разные ошибки, поэтому разные вопросы создаю...

Comment: Сейчас вот JSON сериализацию пытаюсь сделать, и вроде получается, но там другая проблема, и сейчас под него вопрос создавать........

Comment: А нет, мне хватило мозга справиться с JSONом xD поэтому вопрос остался только за XML, и я учту, что вопрос надо редактировать, если что-то не понятно, прости, и спасибо

Comment: Ладно с XML тоже справился, просто решил сериализовать и диссериализовать массивом, и все получилось

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пойдём по порядку.

Вы грузите xml-файл в память: `xDoc.Load("country.xml");`. Добавляете в него данные об Армении и сохраняете: `xDoc.Save("country.xml");`.
При каждом запуске программы добавляется ещё один узел с Арменией. Их становится всё больше и больше, если только в другом месте эти данные не удаляются или сам файл не приводится в первоначальное состояние.
Это ответ на вопрос, заданный в самом конце

> второй раз дублируется страна Армения

---

В этой строке: `new FileStream("country.xml", FileMode.Open)` - открывается **существующий** файл. На это указывает параметр `FileMode.Open`. В файле уже есть информация. Вы её не стираете, а пишете новую прямо поверх неё, с самого начала.
Раньше там была информация о нескольких странах, а сериализуется только одна страна, поэтому новый xml короче, вот и остаются остатки предыдущего текста.

---

> Корневой элемент пропал

Потому что вы его не создаёте. Сериализуется класса `country`, поэтому корневым элементом становится `country`.

> атрибут первого элемента "Russia" тоже заменился каким то текстом

`xmlns:xsi` и `xmlns:xsd` - это пространства имён, которые использует сериализатор для своей работы.
В вашем классе `country` нет свойства `name`, нет кода для создания xml-атрибута из него.

---

Ещё отмечу: `new FileStream("country.xml", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))` - параметр `FileMode.OpenOrCreate` означает "создать или открыть". Нет никакого смысла создавать новый файл и пытаться что-то прочитать из него. Он будет пустой! Поэтому только `Open`.